# How to generate XML containing table and/or column COMMENTs in Oralce?

Tags: xml, oracle, comments

In need to generate XML with list of tables and comlumns comments.

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_COMMENTS; -- my tables

| TABLE_NAME | TABLE_TYPE | COMMENT     |
-----------------------------------------
| table_a    | TABLE      | t.A comment |
| table_b    | TABLE      | t.B comment |


SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_COMMENTS; -- my comments

| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | COMMENT      |
-------------------------------------------
| table_a    | col_1       | c.A1 comment |
| table_a    | col_2       | c.A2 comment |
| table_b    | col_1       | c.B1 comment |
| table_b    | col_2       | c.B2 comment |
```

XML description of table, witch I need:

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_XML(REPLACE(OBJECT_TYPE, ' ', '_'), OBJECT_NAME) xml
FROM USER_OBJECTS
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE IN ('TABLE');
```

And the question is: how can I get equivalent XML for my comments?

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_XML('COMMENT', TABLE_NAME) xml
FROM USER_TAB_COMMENTS; -- doesn't work
```

Best regards and thanks for helping.

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:233014204543

Comment: select  dbms_metadata.GET_DEPENDENT_XML('COMMENT','table_name') from dual; S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get one row per item:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT(
         "TABLE",
         XMLFOREST(
           table_name,
           table_type,
           comments
         )
       ).getClobVal() As xml
FROM   user_tab_comments;
```

To get one row with all the XML nested within:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT(
         "TABLES",
         XMLAGG(
           XMLELEMENT(
             "TABLE",
             XMLFOREST(
               table_name,
               table_type,
               comments
             )
           )
         )
       ).getClobVal() As xml
FROM   user_tab_comments;
```